# Cron PHP File - Headers Already Sent

Tags: php, linux, apache, cron, cpanel

So I know the headers already sent warnings have been discussed multiple times but this error is a little different.

So firstly this is the error I am receiving:

```
[04-Dec-2014 11:51:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent in /home/evaske/public_html/up.php on line 3
[04-Dec-2014 11:51:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent in /home/evaske/public_html/up.php on line 3
```

And here is the PHP code causing it:

```
<?php 

if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

function sendSMS($message){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.infobip.com/api/v3/sendsms/plain");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=MostoSystems&password=Rayidi&sender=MOSTOS&SMSText=".$message."&GSM=917799468478&output=JSON");
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

$url = 'http://googledd.com';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

echo $retcode;

if($retcode == 200) {
    if(!empty($_SESSION['downtime'])){
        $up_time = time();
        $down_time = $_SESSION['downtime'];

        $server_down_time = ($up_time-$down_time);
        $hours = (($server_down_time/60)/60);
        $dt = number_format($hours, 2, '.', '');

        $message = "HOST UP: (".gethostbyname('cphone.mosto.in').") ".$dt." HRS: Hello, This is to inform you that your server just came Online!";
        //sendSMS($message);
    }
}else{
    // Host is down, Take down the time
    if(empty($_SESSION['downtime'])){
        $_SESSION['downtime'] = time();
        $message = "HOST DOWN: (".gethostbyname('cphone.mosto.in')."): Hello, This is to inform you that your server was down now!";
        // sendSMS($message);
    }
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Now the odd thing is, if I run that directly from the browser, then it works fine and nothing is output to the error_log.

However, if I run it as a cron (which is what my client is trying to do, once per minute) then it throws the above error about headers already being sent.

Any reason why running it through cron would be different than running it through a browser?

Comment: Why are you running a script that creates sessions (which are linked to HTTP) via cron (and not HTTP)?

Comment: Run as a CRON, php uses CLI version. CLI version of PHP may have another settings, different from the 'browser' version. You may have the session_autostart set to true in the CLI

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }` is useless, because without `session_start()` there is no `$_SESSION`

Comment: @Quentin This is a clients script. Not mine. They are complaining there is an issue with our server and just want to ensure there isn't.

Comment: @GRSEV Just checked the php.ini file for the CLI and session.auto_start is set to 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Was solved by removing the -q flag from the Cron.

Answer (score -1):

use this:-

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION)){ @session_start(); }
?>
```

Comment: You can use couter or variables instead of session